# How to add non list based OOTB web parts with JSOM Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, csom, jsom

I am attempting to add a Query String Filter Url Web Part to a page programmatically with JSOM and am hitting a dead end.

I see how you can add a web part if you already have the XML like in this guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185010(v%3Doffice.14)

But how can I get the XML for other OOTB web parts? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can go to Web Part Gallery(/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx), find the web part and click "**Edit**" and click "**View Xml**" in the ribbon to get the Xml of the web part.

[image]

The xml of the query string web part as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.QueryStringFilterWebPart,Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:spscore,DwpBdlCannotImport</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="FilterName" type="string">$Resources:spscore,DwpQueryStringFilterName</property>
        <property name="Title" type="string">$Resources:spscore,DwpQueryStringFilterTitle</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">$Resources:spscore,DwpQueryStringFilterDescription</property>
        <property name="ChromeType">None</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string">/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do that with the JSOM or CSOM api